# Delete complete line after tab

Tags: vim

I have a file in following format:

```
"Abu Road","ABR Rajasthan   NWR/North Western   260 m   [5]
```

I want to delete everything after the first tab. So the result will be:

```
"Abu Road","ABR Rajasthan
```

Using gVim on Windows.

Answer (score 7):

This should work  :

```
:%s/\t.*//
```

Comment: I think the `g` is unnecessary

Comment: @FDinoff You are absolutely right but it wouldn't allow me to submit the post since it was 29 characters. The post has to be 30 characters. :P

Comment: @FDinoff if keep golfing, the ending slash is not necessary either. :)

Comment: @Kent then you wouldn't type `\t` you would just hit tab to get `^I`

Comment: For deleting line after tab this is what worked for me on mac.   `:g/\t.*/d`

Answer (score 1):

you could in normal mode do:

<kbd>0</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>TAB</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>